# vbs wrapped ps1 script delivers incomplete results

Tags: powershell, vbscript, gpo

i created a .ps1 script to monitor our clients and it works like a charm. Unfortunatly you always see a powershell window popping up when executing it so I wrapped it into a .vbs script that executes with wscript and use scheduled tasks from GPO to run daily. Both the ps1 file and the vbs file work when I manually execute the scripts but I can't get it to work in the GPO. Everything behaves as it should except mapped drives.

code snipped that works when i run the .ps1 file:

```
$Network_Drive=(Get-SMBMapping | Select-Object -expand RemotePath) -join "`r`n,"
$Network_Drive | Out-File \\a\b\c.csv
```

also works:

```
$Network_Drive= (Get-CimInstance -Class Win32_NetworkConnection | Select -ExpandProperty RemoteName) -join "`r`n,"
```

vbs script:

```
command = "powershell.exe -nologo -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File \\network\link\to\the\script.ps1"
 
set shell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
 
shell.Run command,0
```

Expected result:

```
,\\mapped\drive1\
,\\mapped\drive2\
```

Result:

```
,
,
```

I'm not sure if it's a permission thing with the group policy or if I should use a different method. Everything works as expected when I don't use the .vbs but the ps1 file directly. Network Printer show up as expected.

Comment: Where does your vbs script produce output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my question by putting the scripts on the client and not on a shared drive.

Answer (score 0):

The first question is: Why do you need a VBScript WSH script?

If the goal is to get a list of mapped drives from a VBScript script, there's no need to shell PowerShell and perform output parsing. Instead, just use the `WshNetwork` object directly in your WSH script. Example:

```
Dim WshNetwork
Set WshNetwork = CreateObject("WScript.Network")

Dim Output
Output = ""

Dim Drives, I
Set Drives = WshNetwork.EnumNetworkDrives()
For I = 0 To Drives.Count - 1 Step 2
  If Output = "" Then
    Output = Drives.Item(I) & " => " & Drives.Item(I + 1)
  Else
    Output = Output & vbNewLine & Drives.Item(I) & " => " & Drives.Item(I + 1)
  End If
Next
WScript.Echo Output
```

But again: Why do you need a WSH VBScript script?

Comment: The .ps1 part is only a small snippet of the powershell script i'm running but it was the only part that was not working so I thought the rest of the code does'nt matter that much. I wrapped the .ps1 script in a VBScript script because the powershell script always popped up for a second or so and i wanted to prevent it. I solved the problem in the meantime.